# Creating xml list with multiple items( in one -SOAP/XML message) from csv files using Jmeter

Tags: java, xml, csv, soap, jmeter

i am using jmeter -SOAP/XML-RPC in Thread Group (which reads multiple lines from the csv files)
i am using 2 different csv files (for example: A, B).

the soap contains xml with list inside`(<person list>)`, and i need this list to contain more than one instance, but instead it creates only one instance (of `<person>` in `<person list>` ).

i want it to create more than one instance,

i.e for each line in file A it should read several lines from file B that contains the same `<group_id>` (both files contains "group_id"- with different names obviously : group_id_a, group_id_b),(the lines with the same `group_id_b` in file B are in sequence order).

example for xml in the SOAP:

```
<group_name>${group_name_a}</group_name>
 <group_id>${group_id_a}</group_id>

    <person_list>
      <person>
        <name>${name_b}</name>
        <age>${age_b}</age>
        <city>${city_b}</city>
      </person>
   </person_list>
```

i.e , i need the result to be something like:

```
<group_name>"math"</group_name>
 <group_id>1234</group_id>

    <person_list>
      <person>
        <name>phil</name>
        <age>23</age>
        <city>buenos aires{city_b}</city>
      </person>

        <person>
        <name>liam</name>
        <age>21</age>
        <city>madrid{city_b}</city>
      </person>

        <person>
        <name>brenda</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <city>bariloche</city>
      </person>

        <person>
        <name>martin</name>
        <age>27</age>
        <city>miami</city>
      </person>
   </person_list>
```

because now the result is like that:

```
<group_name>"math"</group_name>
 <group_id>1234</group_id>

    <person_list>
       <person>
        <name>phil</name>
        <age>23</age>
        <city>buenos aires{city_b}</city>
      </person>
  </person_list>
```

i made some csv example(with some unmeaning vars)
[File A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGMac.jpg)

[File B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hugsx.jpg)

so the result should be 3 soap/xml request

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest generating request body dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language. JSR223 PreProcessor provides read/write access to `sampler` object which is most likely [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) so once you generate the correct XML payload you should be able to pass it to the HTTP Request sampler like:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

List<String> csvfile1 = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/file1"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
List<String> csvfile2 = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/file2"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//for each line in file 1

   // for each groupid from file 2

        // append <person> entry

sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("","your XML data","");
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for overview of Groovy scripting in JMeter. If not very comfortable with Groovy - update your question with few lines from CSV files so we could suggest the relevant code.

Comment: how can i create the soap dynamically?
should i create a string and than in some way create a soap from it?
i need also to create several soap so each request have different amount of items in list. (and i updated my question with some example of csv files )
thank you